# How much disk space should I reserve for installing WUBI on Laptop running Window 7?

Tags: installation, wubi, version

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and want to install it on my Laptop to have a try. 
But I don't know how much disk space should I reserve for WUBI[I mean when I install it via window installer, what setting should I use].

I have one hard disk divided into two drives. Window 7 is installed on C:/, so should I install WUBI on D:/ ?

And what would Ubuntu's version be on WUBI? thank you.

My HD has 640GB, they are divided equally, with 201gb free space on C and 85gb on D (i could certainly free much more space here;) ). 15 gb, Then I would run wubi smoothly, right?

Btw, would installing WUBI slow my window 7 down? and how about the time used to start my laptop? thank you.

And, I use D for media storge. But would WUBI-Ubuntu be able to access any folder and file on my drive, even if I install on D? – Andrew 1 min ago edit

one more question, would i be able to change the language setting like English(UK) to English(US), English to Chinese, or etc?

sth just pop up, my window 7 is 64-bit, would there be any problem installing WUBI?

Comment: Have a look at the links I included in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know how much disk space should I reserve for WUBI

Whatever you want: the options in Wubi are in a dropdown box so you can choose whatever you want. It really depends on what you are planning to do with Ubuntu. If it is just for testing you can go for the lowest one. If you plan to start to use it for watching video and you want to save as many as you can on the Ubuntu system you might want to go for 30.
(afaik 30 Gb is the biggest size).

[image]

> So should I install WUBI on D:/?

Feel free to use either C: or D:. Mind you: if you need to re-install Windows you are going to wipe C: and can re-attach D: without formatting D:. So D: is the better option. 
Again: this depends on what you want to use Ubuntu for: if it is temporary C: is just as a good option.

> And what would Ubuntu's version be on WUBI?

Ubuntu will pick the NEWEST official release. In this case it will be the 12.04 version.
See the 1st image I posted: the versio will be shown at the top.

> Would installing WUBI slow my window 7 down?

No. You use Ubuntu seperate from Windows. You get a choise when booting up your system:

[image]

> And how about the time used to start my laptop?

You start either Windows or Ubuntu so this is not an issue.

Some links with more info and lots of images:

- [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)
- [cheap-computing.com](http://www.cheap-computing.com/wubi-ubuntu.html)

Short answer:

- If you want to play safe choose D: and 30 Gb.

Comment: Thank for your information, it's really very helpful. Also, thank for your reminder on how this faq works, I ll amend it later, thz again

Comment: one more question, would i be able to change the language setting like English(UK) to English(US), English to Chinese, or etc?

Comment: Yes, you can change all the settings Ubuntu has (system settings, keyboard and system settings language)

Comment: sth just pop up, my window 7 is 64-bit, would there be any problem installing WUBI?

Answer (score 1):

What are the sizes of your C and D drives? If you open up Computer from the Start Menu, it will show you the sizes and how much is free, e.g. "38 GB free of 100 GB".

I would recommend at least 15GB for Ubuntu, if you are going to be actively using, learning and exploring it.

The version installed by WUBI will be the latest - Ubuntu Precise - 12.04.

WUBI will not slow Windows 7 down -- if you pick Windows 7 from the startup menu, it should start just as fast.

WUBI will install and work just fine whether your Windows is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Thank for answering. My HD has 640GB, they are divided equally, with 201gb free space on C and 85gb on D (i could certainly free much more space here;) ).  
15 gb, Then I would run wubi smoothly, right?

Comment: Btw, would installing WUBI slow my window 7 down? and how about the  time used to start my laptop? thank you.

Comment: It seems you use drive D to store media, etc? In that case, it's best to install to drive C. WUBI-Ubuntu will be able to access all files on drive D. 15GB is "enough", but you can go a little larger if you have the room.

And no, WUBI will not affect your Windows 7 at all, or the time used to start your laptop. The only change will be that you have to pick which one you want to start. If you select Windows, it should start up just as fast as before.

Comment: yes, i use D for media storge. But would WUBI-Ubuntu be able to access any folder and file on my drive, even if I install on D?

Comment: Yes, it will be able to access files on both drives C and D.

Comment: I see. Thank for answering. As soon as i hv backed-up some of my files, I ll join the Ubuntu family ;)

Comment: Windows 64-bit shouldn't matter...